# WCF log details but hide these details to web app

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I have a web application and WCF service hosted in one IIS application.

When an error occurs at WCF level I want to log the details but I want to hide de exception message to the web client / user.

There are several issues:

- When having IncludeExceptionDetails to true the exception detail
  message can be logged but also  flows to the UI (after logging I put
  the throw statement to bubble it upwards)
- When having
  IncludeExceptionDetails to false the exception message is not
  detailed enough to log (but flows to the UI with a masked error
  message, hiding some of the details).

Should I set IncludeExceptionDetails to true, log the exception details it with try catch and rethrow with a general masking exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to log them on the server side? The idea of catching the exceptions on the client is to handle them in proper way by client, to say your client what exactly is wrong ( parameters, authentification, request length and so on). Then client desides what to do with the exception. In your case you the exceptions should be masked to the clients, so make IncludeExceptionDetails=false in your service and log your exceptions on the server side.

The best practice is to do this by implementing the [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751439.aspx) interface in your service. There you can provide the any log logic you want (file, database, email and so on).